# Get date from filename and format it

Tags: header-footer, xstring, datetime, currfile

I was trying to customize the header of a document when I encountered some difficulties. I'm working on this project in which there are several `.tex` files and each one is named as `yyyyMMdd.tex`. My goal is to set the right part of the header as `dddd dd/MM/yyyy`, based on which file it belongs to.

I came up with this command

```
\newcommand{\getfiledate}{
  \StrMid{\currfilebase}{7}{8}/\StrMid{\currfilebase}{5}{6}/\StrLeft{\currfilebase}{4}[\filedate]
  \newdateformat{headerdate}{\shortdayofweekname{\THEDAY},\ \THEDAY/\THEMONTH/\THEYEAR}
  \headerdate{\filedate}
}
```

using `datetime`, `currfile` and `xstring`, but it doesn't work as expected (in some pages it doesn't work at all).

So, I'm here asking how the command could be fixed.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use

`\inputdayfile{20030309}`

defined as

```
\newcommand\inputdayfile[1]{\inputdayfilex#1}

\newcommand\inputdayfilex[8]{%
  \def\thisfileyear{#1#2#3#4}%
  \def\thisfilemonth{#5#6}%
  \def\thisfileday{#7#8}%
  \input{#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8}}
```